# How to generate random booleans in Java using this distribution?

Tags: java, random, boolean

I need to generate some random `boolean` values.

However, I need to ensure that I get exactly 10 `true`'s in a 100 calls. Also, I need the `true` values to be pretty much uniformly distributed (for example, the second `true` will come after 9 `false`'s, the third will come after 7 `false`'s, etc). I tried to implement this using `java.util.Random`'s `nextBoolean()` method, but it seems the `true` values get overcrowded in the beginning. Can anyone help?

Comment: You want exactly 10 `true` values distributed uniformly at random among 100 slots?

Comment: It is not really considered random if you are enforcing that 1 value must occur for every 10 values.

Comment: why not add in a random number of falses. Between 7 and 10 falses then add a true. Keep doing this until your array overflows.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 - Well, they can't be uniformly distributed if you want them more-or-less spread out. You might want to take a look at stratified sampling.

Comment: What's "stratified sampling"? Can you give me an introduction to it?

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 - Divide the overall interval (0-99) into 10 equal bins of 10 (0-9, 10-19, etc.). Then pick one position uniformly at random in each bin to set to `true`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that implements a [stratified sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) technique:

```
boolean[] get10in100() {
    boolean[] result = new boolean[100];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        result[10 * i + rand.nextInt(10)] = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to define the randomness ... here is one possibility:

```
boolean[] ranbool = new boolean[100];
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    ranbool[rng.nextInt(100)] = true;
```

// Following is redundant

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    System.out.print ((ranbool[i]) ? "X" : "O");
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thinking about it, you could also use in as 1 expression (rng.nextDouble() < 0.1)

Comment: You'd need to check that you didn't get the same value from nextInt twice, otherwise you'd get 1 <= N <= 10 booleans per run.

Comment: That would have to do with the definition of randomness. In my solution, approximately 10 out of 100 booleans will be true, and they will have an uniform distribution (nextInt() guarantees this). If the number 100 is not known in advance, the above solution (in comment) is better in that no storage is necessary (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

If you want truly random exactly K trues out of N, you can create an array of K trues and N-K trues, and use the shuffle method on Collections to randomize.

```
List<Boolean> values = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  values.add(true);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
  values.add(false);
}

Collections.shuffle(values);
```

If you want it literally spaced out every 10-ish, use Ted's answer, instead, though it's unclear that you'd really want that from your description.

Answer (score 0):

**little enhanced generic @ted-hopp solution to create distributed prim array of boolean**

maybe it will be helpful for someone:

```
public static boolean[] getRandomBooleanArray(int itemsCount, int truePercentage) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean[] result = new boolean[itemsCount];
    int boolCount = (int) (itemsCount * truePercentage * 0.01); // true items count
    int step = (itemsCount + boolCount - 1) / boolCount; // calculate step
    for (int i = 0; i < boolCount; ++i) {
        int noise = rand.nextInt(step); // calculate noise
        int index = step * i + noise; // initial index
        int realIndex = index < itemsCount ? index : itemsCount-1; // ensure min index
        result[realIndex] = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```